# Trying to create a function to return the total number of letters, uppercase, lowercase, numbers, and others, but can't seem to work - Python

Tags: python

```
def countCharacter(str):
    for i in str:
        letters = 0
        if i.isalpha():
            letters += 1
            
    for i in str:
        upper = 0
        lower = 0
        digit = 0
        others = 0
        if i.isupper():
            upper += 1
        elif i.islower():
            lower += 1
        elif i.isnumeric():
            digit += 1
        else:
            others += 1
            
    list = [letters, upper, lower, digit, others]
    return list
  
print(countCharacter("wh12p3cmaLKND;'$%^&*"))
```

Working on this function that is supposed to print a list of numbers of the respective characters, but don't seem to be working,

just learned python, need help please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code instead:

```
def countCharacter(string):
    letters = sum(i.isalpha() for i in string)
    upper = sum(i.isupper() for i in string)
    lower = sum(i.islower() for i in string)
    digit = sum(i.isdigit() for i in string)
    others = len(string) - sum([upper, lower, digit])
    return [letters, upper, lower, digit, others]
  
print(countCharacter("wh12p3cmaLKND;'$%^&*"))
```

Or to modify your original code:

```
def countCharacter(string):
    letters = 0
    for i in string:
        if i.isalpha():
            letters += 1

    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    digit = 0
    others = 0
    for i in string:
        if i.isupper():
            upper += 1
        elif i.islower():
            lower += 1
        elif i.isnumeric():
            digit += 1
        else:
            others += 1

    return [letters, upper, lower, digit, others]
  
print(countCharacter("wh12p3cmaLKND;'$%^&*"))
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because you're overriding the variables and setting them back to `0` on every iteration.